# Exactly 5 cards of a standard, well-shuffled deck of 52 cards are dealt to a player.

Tags: probability

Exactly 5 cards of a standard, well-shuffled deck of 52 cards are dealt to a player. How many possibilities are there for the player to get a flush but not a straight flush? A straight but not a straight flush? (Within a hand, the order in which cards are received doesn’t matter.)
Note: Find the definitions of those terms yourself. For example, a hand containing ♣Q♢K♡A♠2♠3 is a straight; a hand containing ♠6♠7♠10♠J♠K is a flush; a hand containing ♢K♢A♢2♢3♢4 is a straight flush.

Can someone please help me solve this question? I got it completely wrong on my homework with no feedback from my professor and I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Please include your calculation so that we might spot the error.  Should say, under usual rules, neither of the "straights" you list are actually straights.  At best, an Ace can be high or low, but not both in the same hand. Often the rules specify high or low, but sometimes an Ace can be either (though, as I say, not both at the same time).  If you are using eccentric rules, you should specify them clearly.

Comment: Should say:  Once you clarify the definition, it should be an easy matter to count the hands in which every card has the same suit and count the straight flushes and count the total number of hands, which is all you need.

Comment: I didn't convince the dealer that I was holding a straight with QKA23 last time it happened to me.

Comment: As an aside, $QKA23$ is commonly *not* considered a straight.  That is a [wrap around straight](https://www.888poker.com/magazine/poker-terms/wrap-around-straight) and under standard rules (*for example as used by WSOP*) does not count, the hand then being either a flush if all suits the same or just an Ace-High highcard hand.